# How can we set the position of subtitle, currently displaying at the bottom of the screen, we need to set it 30px up from bottom?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video-streaming, html5-video

Current display position of subtitle is bottom on the screen, we need to set subtitle 30px above from bottom.

Comment: show your html,css code

Comment: you need to replicate your problem by sharing the relevant code ( CSS HTML etc. ) . see here how to ask a question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't bother at all to write a valid SO-question and without any knowledge of your code...

Given the fact your subtitles are already at the bottom I guess you have something like:

```
.subtitle-selector {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Well... all you have to do is change that 0 to 30px.

But it would be really helpful to see some code. currently it's just a shot in the dark